# Creating dir using array in PHP

Tags: php

I have an array structure like the one below. I want to create a folder within folder using this array. How do I do this?

```
$folder=array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "img"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "dummies"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "slides"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "01.jpg"
}
```

I have tried like this but it does not solve my problem..

```
 $imglength=count($folder);
 $i=0;
 $fold=$i<($imglength-1);
 while(!file_exists($fold))
 {
  mkdir($fold);
 }
```

Comment: `$fold=$i<($imglength-1);` What is that? You know that this variable will just contain either `true` or `false`, right?

Comment: file_exists( $path_from_root . '/somedir/file/' . $fold ) check from root directory folder exits or not

Comment: how about `array_map('mkdir', $array)` ? (if file/dir exists, it will fail, but continue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is one way of doing it. Probably not the most efficient way of doing it, but it works.

```
<?php
    $folders = Array(
        Array("img", "dummies", "slides", "01.jpg"),
        Array("img_24", "dummy", "slideshows", "65.png")
    );

    for ($i=0;$i<count($folders);$i++) {
        for ($j=0;$j<count($folders[$i]);$j++) {
            $path .= $folders[$i][$j] . "/";
            mkdir($path);
        }
        unset($path);
    }
?>
```

It basically reads the array and places each name into a single variable, which extends itself so that it creates a path. The JPEG file is not created, of course, but that's something you can do with [file_put_contents](http://php.net/function.file-put-contents) or so, just give it another array value referring as "file" instead of the default "folder" definition. Then when it reads the definition it automatically creates a file instead of a folder and then writes in the bitmap data.

**EDIT:** For file creation, you can use file_put_contents like I explained above, I made a small piece of code to demonstrate the use.

```
<?php
    $folders = Array(
        Array("img", "dummies", "slides", Array("01.jpg", "11abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz")),
        Array("img_24", "dummy", "slideshows", Array("65.png", "22abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz"))
    );

    for ($i=0;$i<count($folders);$i++) {
        for ($j=0;$j<count($folders[$i]);$j++) {
            $path .= (gettype($folders[$i][$j]) != "array" ? $folders[$i][$j] . "/" : $folders[$i][$j][0]);
            if (gettype($folders[$i][$j]) != "array") {
                mkdir($path);
            }else{
                file_put_contents($path, (isset($folders[$i][$j][1]) ? $folders[$i][$j][1] : "nil"));
            }
        }
        unset($path);
    }
?>
```

The JPEG file's second value is used for the content of the file. You can put the bitmap data in that by reading the file you're using and then placing it in as a value. That way you get the image created properly.

Comment: ThanKYou so much!!!
last thing ahh i dn want to create that 01.jpg folder instead i want to put that image file into that folder... please do help me i tht too... please.. :)

Comment: Mhm. If you want to have multiple folder paths, then you can make multiple arrays within the base array. Then just add another for-loop for the sub arrays, this way you won't have to do the same for-loop for each one individually.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>

<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html> 

<?php

  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
        echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  }
  else
  {
        $tmp_name   =   $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
  }


  $folders    =  array("img","dummies","slides");



foreach($folders as $folder)
{

  $folder_path .= $folder."/";


    while(!file_exists($folder_path))
    {

        mkdir($folder_path);

    }


}


move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$folder_path/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
```

Comment: ThanKYou so much!!! last thing ahh i dn want to create that 01.jpg folder instead i want to put that image file into that folder... please do help me i tht too... please.. :)

Comment: @user3048483 the image will be already uploaded via a form ??

Comment: @user3048483 ok updated code for you , hope this is what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

Just try

```
<?php 
$folder=array(array("img","dummies","slides","01.jpg"));


$imglength=count($folder);
 $i=0;
 $fold=$i<($imglength-1);

for($k=0;$k<$imglength;$k++)
{
    $sub_array_count=count($folder[$k]);
    $tmp='';
    for($j=0;$j<$sub_array_count;$j++)
    {
        if($j==0)
        {
            mkdir($folder[$k][$j]);


        }else
        {
            echo $folder[$k][($j-1)];
            echo "<br>";
            echo $tmp.=$folder[$k][($j-1)]."/";
            mkdir($tmp.$folder[$k][$j]);

        }
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: thank You for ur precious tym an precious work... :)