# create multiple directories using loop in php

Tags: php, directory

I am taking data from text file( data is: daa1 daa2 daa3 on separate lines) then trying to make folders with exact name but only daa3 folders is created. Also when i use integer it creates all folders, same is the case with static string i.e "faraz".

```
$file = __DIR__."/dataFile.txt";
$f = fopen($file, "r");
$line =0;
 while ( $line < 5 )
{
    $a = fgets($f, 100); 

    $nl = mb_strtolower($line);
    $nl = "checkmeck/".$nl;
    $nl =  $nl."faraz"; // it works for static value i.e for faraz
//$nl =  $nl.$a; // i want this to be the name of folder
    if (!file_exists($nl)) {
    mkdir($nl, 0777, true);


}
$line++;
}
```

kindly help

Comment: It would be so much simpler using a database. Now, you most likely need to use a `foreach` loop instead of a `while` or in conjunction with.

Comment: What is the value of $a? File systems don't like special characters very well. Could be an issue with that.

Comment: [`The Q&A's here`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21672960/) may very well help you.

Comment: the best function to foreach line by line in php is `feof` other functions will kill server memory if the file is large

Comment: use `feof` will fix your issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `feof` function its much better to get file content also line by line

Check this full code

```
 $file         = __DIR__."/dataFile.txt";
$linecount    = 0;
$handle       = fopen($file, "r");
$mainFolder   = "checkmeck";

while(!feof($handle))
{
  $line       = fgets($handle);
  $foldername = $mainFolder."/".trim($line);

  //$line is line name daa1,daa2,daa3 etc
  if (!file_exists($foldername)) {
    mkdir($foldername, 0777, true);
  }
  $linecount++;
  unset($line);
}

fclose($handle);
```

output folders

```
1countfaraz
2countfaraz
3countfaraz
```

Comment: i have done this already what i m asking is how it could name the generated folders exactly the same as in dataFile.Txt (names is datafile are daa1, daa2 and daa3)

Comment: change `$foldername = $mainFolder.$linecount."countfaraz";` to `$foldername = $mainFolder.$line;`

Comment: Try now this should work fine , i have updated the code

Comment: OMG YOU ARE SUCH A HERO.. WONDERFUL

Comment: glad its worked , next time use `trim` to remove any spaces inside the line

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you're having trouble with your code, but I find it to be more straightforward to use `file_get_contents()` instead of `fopen()` and `fgets()`:

```
$file = __DIR__."/dataFile.txt";
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
$lines = explode("\n", $contents);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $nl = "checkmeck/". $line;
    if (!file_exists($nl)) {
        echo 'Creating file '. $nl . PHP_EOL;
        mkdir($nl, 0777, true);
        echo 'File '. $nl .' has been created'. PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo 'File '. $nl .' already exists'. PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

The `echo` statements above are for debugging so that you can see what your code is doing. Once it is working correctly, you can remove them.

So you get the entire file contents, split it (`explode()`) by the newline character (`\n`), and then loop through the lines in the file. If what you said is true, and the file looks like:

```
daa1
daa2
daa3
```

...then it should create the following folders:

```
checkmeck/daa1
checkmeck/daa2
checkmeck/daa3
```

Comment: I m getting daa4 folder only not daa3 daa2 and daa1 folder. problem is still thr

Comment: its creating only daa3 folder

Comment: @FarazMukhtar: I added debug output to my sample code so you can see what the code is doing when you run it.

Comment: hhmm sir I appreciate your effort but this isnt running here getting daa4 folder only.. although receiving echo that file has been created but no such folder show up other than daa4

Comment: never use `file_get_contents` to open local files if `allow_url_fopen` is closed on the server the function wont work 99% of hosting servers is closing `allow_url_fopen`

Comment: @JackKFouani: 99%? Source? I've used it all the time on tons of different servers without checking the `allow_url_fopen` setting and never run into a problem.

Comment: @jack: sir i lastly it was creating folders but after using allow_url it isnt

Comment: if you pass `allow_url_fopen` the `CSF` will suspect the script and block it , if you pass `CSF` `Mod_security` will block the content

Comment: According to the [PHP documentation](http://us1.php.net/file_get_contents), "file_get_contents() is the preferred way to read the contents of a file into a string. It will use memory mapping techniques if supported by your OS to enhance performance." So that's what I've always used and never run into any problems. Just saying. Not sure where you came up with the idea that it won't work on 99% of hosting servers, unless I'm just the luckiest man alive when it comes to this function.

Comment: @Travesty3 agreed `file_get_contents` is safe to be used , @JackKFouani you are so wrong